# Search bar returning only first element from data array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

currently I am trying to implement my search bar, but something is wrong and I can't figure it out what it is. Here is the code, and explanation.

```
//global variable for empty array, its type of Any cause I am getting data from network call
var filteredData: [Any]!
//these are my models, which I am using to display them on screen after mapping in network function
var bookedTrips: [BookedTripsForView]?

func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filteredData = bookedTrips
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        filteredData = []
        if searchText == "" {
            filteredData = bookedTrips
        }else {
            for trip in (bookedTrips)! {
                if trip.tripName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()){
                    filteredData.append(trip)
                  //if I type, lets say Barcelona, in console its printed correct result, 
                  //but its displaying only first trip in my array, which is Berlin
                    print("filteredDataArray after appending print: \(String(describing: filteredData))")
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I hope that my explanation is ok, if something's not clear, I will refactor my question. Thanks in advance.

[Here is picture of my screen and console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVl8N.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if let filter = filteredData {
                return filter.count
            } else if let data = bookedTrips {
                return data.count
            }
            return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.tripInfo) as! TripsListDetailCell
    
    if let trips = bookedTrips?[indexPath.row] {
        cell.configure(trips: trips)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you show ` tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` please

Comment: The declaration of your arrays is very bad practice. Declare both  `filteredData` and `bookedTrips` as empty non-optional array of the same type: `var filteredData = [BookedTripsForView]()` and `var bookedTrip = [BookedTripsForView]()`

Comment: @Mat my question is updated, I wanted in cellForRowAt write this: if let trips = filteredData?[indexPath.row], but I get error: Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'BookedTripsForView'

Comment: the problem is that you are always using booked trips array even when you are filtering so it always returns the first item of this array counting one from the filtering array.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta answer  should work

Comment: can you please check my answer in comments, I have new problem about viewForHeaderInSection question. thanks

Comment: @iosguy Forget `viewForHeaderInSection` as long as the data source doesn't support sections.

Comment: Please tell me one thing, while searching how your tableview should look like? Would it display as different sections or all trips in one section?

Comment: When screen is opened, all of my trips should be displayed and categorized with titles previous, current and upcoming, those three things I get from json as property string for each trip, after I search for specific trip, my tableview should update i show only what i searched, as well in which category is that trip that user searched for @RahulDasgupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple (One line filter)

```
var filteredData = [BookedTripsForView]()
var bookedTrips = [BookedTripsForView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bookedTrips = fetchFromAPIorDB()
    filteredData = bookedTrips
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.tripInfo) as! TripsListDetailCell
    cell.configure(trips: filteredData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = bookedTrips
    }
    else {
        filteredData = bookedTrips.filter({ $0.tripName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How should I implement function viewForHeaderInSection? In response inside every trip I get status of trip (current, upcoming, previous). I would like to sort them by status. If I put this inside viewForHeaderInSection : 
if isSearching {cell.configure(trips: filteredData[section])} else { cell.configure(trips:bookedTrips[section])}
        return cell
I get index out of range on bookedTrips[section]
If i comment that line, it works until I make mistake in search bar, lets say instead of Barcelona I type Bars, it throws error on filteredData[section] index out of range

Answer (score 0):

create enum for page mood like this for readable code:

```
enum PageMood {
    
    case normal
    case search
}
```

and create variable

```
var pageMode: PageMood = .normal
```

set normal for first first if search and change pageMode to search like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    if searchText == "" {
        pageMode = .normal
    }else {
        pageMode = .search
        filteredData = bookedTrips?.filter({ item -> Bool in
            return (item.tripName?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ?? false)
        })
    }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

change define datasource like this:

```
var bookedTrips: [BookedTripsForView]?
var filteredData: [BookedTripsForView]?
```

and inside set numberOfItem:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if pageMode == .search {
        return filteredData.count ?? 0
    } else {
        return bookedTrips.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

if only one item find، Maybe your data has only one item similar to the search text.

Comment: I just implemented this, but nothing changed, still same result, can u please check my question again? I edited it, i think the problem is in tableview cell for row at function

Comment: edited my sample code. check again code and check result after filter datasource before line self.tableView.reloadData() for find how much find result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var isSearching: Bool = false // As global variable
 var bookedTrips: [BookedTripsForView]? = []
 var filteredData: [BookedTripsForView]? = []

 
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    filteredData = []
    if searchText == "" {
        isSearching = false
    }else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredData = bookedTrips.filter { (trip) -> Bool in
            if trip.tripName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()){
                return true
            } 
            return false
    }

        
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

//Tableview delegate

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isSearching {
            return self.filteredData.count
        }
        return bookedTrips.count
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.tripInfo) as! TripsListDetailCell

  if isSearching {
      cell.configure(trips: filteredData[indexPath.row])
  }
  else {
     cell.configure(trips: bookedTrips[indexPath.row])

  }
  return cell
```

}

Answer (score 0):

And now, since I changed my variables to this :

```
var filteredData = [BookedTripsForView]()
var bookedTrips = [BookedTripsForView]()
```

**I have one more problem in sections, added comment inside**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: Cells.sectionTitle) as! TripsListHeaderCell
    
    if isSearching {
        cell.configure(trips: filteredData[section])
    }
    else {
        cell.configure(trips: bookedTrips[section])
    }
    return cell
}
```

How should I implement function viewForHeaderInSection? In response inside every trip I get status of trip (current, upcoming, previous). I would like to sort them by status. If I put this inside viewForHeaderInSection :

```
if isSearching { 
  cell.configure(trips: filteredData[section])
} else { 
  cell.configure(trips:bookedTrips[section])
} 
return cell
```

I get index out of range on bookedTrips[section] If i comment that line, it works until I make mistake in search bar, lets say instead of Barcelona I type Bars, it throws error on filteredData[section] index out of range

In my response, every trip have trip status property which has type string, can I even sort them by that property?

Comment: This is very bad way of coding. Section is for showing some sections if necessary. You shouldn't return cells in section.

Comment: yeah, i tought so, still learning and in begginings of ios, do you have any suggestion for better solution to this?

Comment: According to your code in the question you don't have (multiple) sections so this method is pointless.

Comment: @vadian I actually do have, in response I have trips categorized by upcoming, current and previous trips, which I did have in my tableview, you can see in my question in picture, CURRENT header section.

Comment: Maybe but your data source  doesn’t consider sections at all. The data source array is clearly one-dimensional.

Comment: yeah, you are right. You have any advice how should I show those properties?

Comment: To enable sections you need a two-dimensional array or – better – a wrapper struct `struct Section { let name : String; var items : [BookedTripsForView] }`

Comment: Then you have to arrange your datasource like what you needed to display. For every section there should be an array of trips.

Comment: What does trip status contain?

Comment: @RahulDasgupta https://pastebin.com/NagPcymu this is my json, so you can see better